# findOneAndUpdate return old document even {new:true} is passed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
const query = { uuid: '12212121212112' };
const values = { $set: {name:'av'} };
const result = await databaseConnection.collection('person');
let data = await result.findOneAndUpdate(query, values, { new: true });
console.log(data) //old document getting printed
```

This is my code. In here I am using `{new: true}` but somehow still its returning the old document instead of the updated one.

Configuration is-

```
 "mongodb": "^3.5.7",
 "mongoose": "^5.9.17",
```

node version- `v14.17.3`

What is wrong with this?

P.S.- In another project with the same configuration it's working fine.

Comment: Try  **{returnNewDocument: true}**

Comment: @Nik Already tried. Its also not working

Answer (score 1):

**Replace line no.4 with below:**

```
let data = await result.findOneAndUpdate(query, values, { returnOriginal: false, returnDocument: "after" });
```

Works for me !
Thanks

Comment: This solution works I tried this too. But returnOriginal is deprecated. And I and using the latest mongoose version so. I trying to find out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @AnureshVerma Hope you have not tried **{ returnNewDocument: true, returnDocument: "after" }** Works for me with latest mongodb & mongoose check gif [demo](https://ibb.co/bNtPwhC)

Comment: @AnureshVerma Have you tried the above mentioned in comment ? 
I don't understand why are you using Mongoose if you are doing Schemaless architecture , go with pure Nodejs MongoDB Driver.

Answer (score 0):

try this way...

```
let result = await db1.updateOne({ _id: 'XXXXXXXXX' }, { $set: { name: 'My name' } }, { returnNewDocument: true });
    console.log(result.data.value) //new document getting printed
```

Also check this working example

https://mongoplayground.net/p/hJgsH7V0Mps

Comment: Thanks, But I am looking for what is wrong with my code. Not alternatives.

Comment: let data = await result.findOneAndUpdate(query, values, { returnNewDocument: true });
console.log(data.data.value) //new document getting printed

Comment: my mongodb version  "mongodb": "^3.6.3",

Comment: @SelvaMary He is using Mongoose driver for interacting with mongo instance not MongoDB Native, he already tried { returnNewDocument: true } and its not working for me too, but using **{ returnNewDocument: true, returnDocument: "after" }** Works with latest version